# Uploading images to Canon Connect Station CS100

Tags: canon

When connecting my Windows 10 PC to the CS100 using Chrome, it appears as if the CS100 recognises my PC as a mobile device.

As such, I am presented with 6 upload slots and have to select images individually for upload. According to the manual, when connecting via a PC I should be able to select multiple images and drag & drop them into the browser, uploading upto 1,000 at a time.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Connect Station is probably trying to present different interfaces to web clients based the browser's User-Agent string. Because their list of tested/supported host OS / browser combinations is so limited, my hunch is that their User-Agent identification is too strict, and they fall back to presenting a mobile interface.

Try installing a User Agent switcher extension in your web browser. There are a handful out there. You might have to try several switcher extensions until you find one you like, that can allow you to fine-tune your presented operating system version and browser information.

Even though the user manual only lists Chrome and Safari as supported browsers, a different modern browser (Opera, Firefox, Edge) with the appropriate User-Agent string might work just fine with your Connect Station.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but none of the different user agents seemed to have an effect.